# Blogger, tumblr option for custom template

Tags: templates, blogger

How these application allow users to upload their own templates? How is this possible?

Do they have some kind of a their own template engine or..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tumblr** gives you two options to include your own theme:

1. If it is just for personal use: by changing the html of the theme. If you go to your tumblr-website and click on the `customize` button, you can edit the html. In the header file the content of your .css must be pasted between the `<style type="text/css"> </style>` tags. And you can add some javascript there. For the html I suggest to read the manual that Mirko Adari suggested: [Tumblr Theme manual](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)
2. If you want it to be a theme on itself: submit your theme to the Theme Garden: [Tumblr Theme Garden](http://www.tumblr.com/themes/new)

**Blogger** is a bit more rigid. Also there you can change your html file. Keep in mind that it's markup for posts is different then Tumblr. Also custom CSS files can be added ([more information on that](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176245)). If you are less familiar with css and html Blogger offers some buttons so that you can change the basics to your own needs. Blogger also offers a way to backup and restore your theme. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://www.bloggerbuster.com/2012/04/how-to-back-up-restore-and-upload-new.html). This template file must be an `.xml` file. More information on the markup of this xml-template can be found [here](http://www.ourblogtemplates.com/2007/06/structure-of-blogger-template-code.html).